# Trying to get bluetooth to work in guest windows vista in virtual box

Tags: bootcamp, windows, bluetooth, virtualbox

I assigned the bluetooth host controller to the guest and vista detected it. I installed the driver that boot camp is providing for my computer and for 32bit windows, which is broadcom 4.0.3.0 from 2011. The driver installs fine, but the device fails with code 43. I am stuck here. I can't find any different driver or see what the issue with the code 43 is. Any newer drivers I saw are large installers (>120MB) that fail installation when they can't detect the "bluetooth device".

The 4.0.3.0 driver I used can also be downloaded from the following page, note that none of the other downloads installs for me.
https://www.driverscape.com/download/apple-broadcom-built-in-bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

Got the driver updated using Driver Booster application. Oddly the device shows up in the device manager as "BlueSoleil Generic Bluetooth Driver", the device does not show an error now, however, I can't discover any bluetooth devices :|. Still stuck